# Oracle installation failed on AWS redhat EC2 instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I'm trying to install oracle on AWS redhat instance. Follow the steps given on this url: http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_oracle_11g_xe_on And when I run config command as follows

> /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

It gives following error.

> Database Configuration failed.  Look into
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details

When I check the log files it shows following errors.

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available  Process ID: 0  Session ID: 0 Serial
>   number: 0

It seems specific issue on AWS cloud instance. 
Is it because of swap memory?
Or is it because of port issue?
I'm using micro instance on it.

How can I get through?

Answer (score 0):

this might be an EC2 security group issue and outbound access to the network on some port being used by the installer (license check, maybe?).

if your EC2 instance is very tightly locked down, you could test if it's a security group issue by adding a new Outbound security group rule to allow all TCP traffic out to anywhere on the internet (0.0.0.0/0)

for example, the install might be trying to hit a remote licensing server endpoint via HTTP or HTTPS but your security group doesn't allow that traffic out.

perhaps there's a 'verbose' flag that you can run the installer with that can give you more info about what it's failing on? HTH